# Cloud firestore '!=' query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

According to [firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), I can perform the equivalent of a '!=' query by combining '>' and '<' queries:

> Queries with a != clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported, you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause where("age", ">", 30).

But how exactly do I do that? If possible, please provide the code for that exact example (query for result != 30).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, using a query like the following one will not work (based on the example on cities, found in the documentation you refer to):

```
var query = citiesRef.where("population", ">", 860000).where("population", "<", 860000);
```

I think the documentation excerpt you refer to means that you have to declare two queries (see below) and combine, in your code, the results of these two queries.

```
var query1 = citiesRef.where("population", ">", 860000);
var query2 = citiesRef.where("population", "<", 860000);
```

or

```
var query1 = yourRef.where("age", ">", "30");
var query2 = yourRef.where("age", "<", "30");
```

Here is a code that works for the cities example from the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). Open these two HTML pages one after the other. The first one will create some cities records. The second one will concatenate the results of the two queries in one array and print it in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>2</title>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: ".....",
            authDomain: ".....",
            databaseURL: ".....",
            projectId: "....."
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var db = firebase.firestore();
        var citiesRef = db.collection('cities');

    citiesRef.doc("SF").set({
     name: "San Francisco", state: "CA", country: "USA",
     capital: false, population: 860000,
     regions: ["west_coast", "norcal"] });
    citiesRef.doc("LA").set({
     name: "Los Angeles", state: "CA", country: "USA",
     capital: false, population: 3900000,
     regions: ["west_coast", "socal"] });
    citiesRef.doc("DC").set({
     name: "Washington, D.C.", state: null, country: "USA",
     capital: true, population: 680000,
     regions: ["east_coast"] });
    citiesRef.doc("TOK").set({
     name: "Tokyo", state: null, country: "Japan",
     capital: true, population: 9000000,
     regions: ["kanto", "honshu"] });
   citiesRef.doc("BJ").set({
     name: "Beijing", state: null, country: "China",
     capital: true, population: 21500000,
     regions: ["jingjinji", "hebei"] });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>2</title>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: ".....",
            authDomain: ".....",
            databaseURL: ".....",
            projectId: "....."
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var db = firebase.firestore();
        var citiesRef = db.collection('cities');

        var query1 = citiesRef.where("population", ">", 860000);
        var query2 = citiesRef.where("population", "<", 860000);

        var fullArray = [];    

        query1.get()
            .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                console.log(querySnapshot.docs);
                (querySnapshot.docs).forEach((element, index, array) => {
                    console.log(element.data().population);
                });
                fullArray = fullArray.concat(querySnapshot.docs);
                return query2.get();
            })
            .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                console.log(querySnapshot.docs);
                (querySnapshot.docs).forEach((element, index, array) => {
                    console.log(element.data().population);
                });
                fullArray = fullArray.concat(querySnapshot.docs);
                console.log('Final resulting array:');
                fullArray.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                    console.log(element.data().population);
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok then how do you join them into 1 after that? There's quite a lot of complication here. Removing duplication, for one - surely you're not telling me to do an O(n^2) loop through 2 snapshots that are practically the entire database?
Also I need code example because firebase docs is a complete mess. Even for this solution, I know what to do, but can't find how to do it in the docs.

Comment: The `get()` method on a `Query` will return a `QuerySnapshot`. As explained in the doc, "a `QuerySnapshot` contains zero or more `DocumentSnapshot` objects representing the results of a query. The documents can be accessed as an array via the `docs` property...". You can easily merge the two arrays.

Comment: I've added a full working code. IMHO I don't think the Firebase documentation is a "complete mess", on the contrary....

Comment: In the end your solution is the best one I could find, though I'm still concerned about looping through all returned values again to build the final result. There's very small different comparing with getting the entire collection and `filter()` by myself imo.

Comment: "There's very small different comparing with getting the entire collection and filter() by myself imo" -> indeed, it depends how large is the "excluded" set (i.e. how many items you have with age = 30)

Answer (score 0):

You question, can found the answer on the official document.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

**Query limitations**

> Queries with a != clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although
>   the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported, you can
>   get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause
>   where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause where("age", ">",
>   30).